# Detect select change in UISegmentedControl From UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm trying to detect if UISegmentedControl selection changed to do an action but nothing happen when I change the selection ,I got UISegmentedControl from a tag in the cell

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
UISegmentedControl *doing = (UISegmentedControl *)[cell viewWithTag:512];

 NSString *done = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[_myarraytask objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"done"]];
if ([done isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {



doing.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

if(doing.selectedSegmentIndex==0){


    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Task finish ?" message:@"Please confirm" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Confirm" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    }]];


    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        [self closeAlertview:(cell)];
    }]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    });



}
}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how `UISegmentedControl`, works you need to assign it a selector method event (`UIControlEventValueChanged`). This way it will listen to the index change then call that function.`

so in your cell

```
UISegmentedControl *doing = (UISegmentedControl *)[cell viewWithTag:512];
[doing addTarget:self
          action:@selector(action:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

then move that code out of the delegate to its own function:

```
-(void)action(id)sender{
    UISegmentedControl* doing = (UISegmentedControl*)sender;
    if(doing.selectedSegmentIndex==0){
     //...
    }else{
     //...
    }
}
```